# From docker container cant access 192.168.2.* network which is under VPN

Tags: docker, docker-network

The container connects to external servers and executes code there.

These external servers are behind a VPN.
From the local host I can connect to them, either by name or by direct IP.

But for some reason, to the servers in the subnet 192.168.2.* I can not connect from the container. But I can connect to subnets 192.168.123.* (also under VPN).

DNS servers are given to me through the VPN 192.168.2.1 and 192.168.123.1. I tried to assign the same DNS to the container through the key --dns, nothing changes.

Pinging by domain name `server1.company.com` extracts correct address 192.168.2.200 and thats all.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Are you using a bridge network and docker-compose.yml ?

Comment: Maybe the 2.* subnet overlaps with your container's inner subnet

Comment: @asultan904 I am not using docker composer, this process starts with just `docker run`, and I tried bridge, host drivers also - nothing helped

Comment: @C1sc0 ifconfig in the container shows that there is no intersection, by default there is 172.* subnets.

Comment: check the routing with: ip r g 192.168.2.200 what is the output?

Comment: @C1sc0 
```# ip r g 192.168.2.200
192.168.2.200 via 172.17.0.1 dev eth0 src 172.17.0.2 uid 0
    cache```

Comment: What I found out right now, that everything works fine. I dont know what happend, but after this post  just left everything as it is. Just today after some system updated I restarted macbook and now I cant reproduce that error.  (

Comment: Some glitch in the matrix :D it happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question.

There's no magic here, after all.

with the command `scutil --dns` I found out which nameservers added by VPN and just added them to `docker run ...` command like:

```
--dns=192.168.2.1 --dns=192.168.123.1 --publish-all
```

and now it works fine.

PS: But I still dont have any idea how it worked before (.